# Add data to same documnet category in mupltiple UIs

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm a beginner to Flutter and Firebase I'm still referring to tutorials so bear with me on that. I'm creating a flutter app. Currently there is a product add process. In first UI user add name and description.So in first UI I make a new document category with a unique id in Firestore, yes I get it. Next UI let's say add description. So the problem is I need to add those details for that previously created same document id. What is the best practice or most efficient to do that. Assuming I have separate collections for 'user' and 'products' as well a user can insert multiple products (So  can't use uid as the document id for product).

Also if this is a duplicate, feel free to add it here. Because I didn't find answer for this.

Edit:
As more info asked,

1. First ui have text inputs of product name and description. So I add a Firestore query with an auto defined document id, a new document with 'product id' and 'product desc'.
2. 2nd UI I have to add product category. So I add a new text input for that (or maybe a drop-down'). Now as you can see I need to add that category info that same document previously made. But right now we are on a new dart file. So how can I enter those info to that same document id.

My assumptions are whether pass data between dart files or, as this Firestore db already has a 'users' collection, add a new line to that corresponding user's document saying 'last edited product id'. So in the 2nd ui we can fetch those data from Firestore to find the corresponding document id for the 'product'. ( Note: in this Firestore db, each user's document id is the same as uid in firebase auth. So I can find corresponding user's document id in Firestore db by firebase auth id)

Comment: Instead of asking for a best practice for your specific use-case (see [problematic question types: What is the best/easiest/fastest way to do X?](https://overflow.tips/problematic-questions#what-is-the-besteasiestfastest-way-to-do-x)), consider showing us the [minimal code that reproduces what you already tried and where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Once we see what you got working and where you got stuck, it is much more likely we can help you with the next step.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: @frankvanPuffelen  I added more details as asked. If more are needed I'm happy to reply

Comment: If I understand correctly you are asking whether you should pass the data between the views, or load the data from the database in each view. Both are valid approaches with their own advantages and disadvantages, so I recommend just starting with the one that seems simplest to you.